# How to reset a parent-managed kid's phone?

Tags: lock-screens, hard-reset, google-family-link

My daughter has changed her lock screen password. Didn't write it down. And had forgotten it. And so her phone is locked.

What I observe is:

- After restart, she's been asked a code. I can't find anyway to reset that code.
- Her phone is connected to the web. I can see today's date on the Family Link page for her account.
- I cannot find a way to switch from user on her phone (i.e. logging with my own account)
- Stopping and Restarting the device is not possible. The phone remains on that lock screen. Only a hard-shutdown is possible (Volume up/Volume down/Power during a few seconds).
- The phone doesn't ring when I ask it to ring from the Family Link page.

I tried various ways to connect to the phone :

- The procedures with *Find My Device* don't work, because :

  - When I connect to Google with my own account, I cannot switch to her account, and hence don't see her phone as candidate phone to work on.
  - When I connect with her account, she has no rights to use that application.
- The Family Link page provides a 6-digits code that changes every hour supposedly providing access to the phone. It doesn't. The phone keeps saying invalid password.
- The Family Link page lets define a new lock screen password. Defining a new password doesn't help despite a hard restart of the phone.

What are my options now ? A hard reset of the phone is acceptable. But even that I don't succeed to do.

---

PS: The phone is a Samsung A03

Comment: If you reboot the phone the phone is in a partially locked state. Is is caused by the file encryption (the phone uses File Based Encryption) which is unable to decrypt personal user data stored on the phone without entering the lock screen PIN at least one time. So at the moment only general device configuration like Wifi passwords are accessible. Not sure if there is a way to recover the phone without performing a factory reset.

Comment: A03 is MediaTek SoC so low level access is available for erasing FRP

Comment: @alecxs I'm afraid that I don't understand your answer. Could you translate it in more "end-user" language ? Thanks.

Comment: just a hint not an answer. unfortunately, not for "end-user"

Answer (score 0):

Turn phone off. If android turn back on holding down volume up and power button until you see startup logo,

if it boots all the way then you did something wrong....

if yours is version 8 or lower should go straight to the recovery mode, from ther you can do factory reset.....

if higher than 8 then while in recovery you have to do an extra step, but sadly everytime i do it i get it by accident....

Hope this helps